# Create something like facebook wall

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I want to create something like Facebook wall. Currently I am getting the data in a json format and displaying using jQuery $each and then appending it to the main div. I am looking for an alternative way of doing this.
The problem in the current code is that i cannot use the div class to call any method like on.click . The on.click method need to be inside the $each to be get called and it gets called the number of object present in data.

And if i want to update the wall then i need to update the data and has to refresh the whole structure. Is there any other way by which i can add the new post to the wall without rebuilding the structure.

```
$.each(data, function () {
    var status_id = this['Id'];
    var like_id = "like" + status_id;
    var commennt_id = "commnet-tem" + status_id;
    var likes = 0;

    $("<div class=\"post-indi\" id=\"post-item" + status_id + "\">" +
        "<div  class=\"post-content\">" +
        " <div class=\"status-profile\" >" +
        "<img src="">" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class=\"content\">" + this['status'] + "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class=\"commentbox-info\">" +
        "<a id=\""+like_id+"\" href=\"#\" class=\"postddlike\">Like</a><img </div></div>").appendTo("div.post");
```

Comment: need to read up on `event delegation`

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method